# I need to create corr matrix on dataset with 144 columns by using python

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, seaborn, correlation

I need to create corr matrix on dataset with 144 columns by using python. But when i try to do this, i getting a bad result (you can see at the picture). So, what do i need to do to make the correlation matrix readable?[image: code and result]

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to add colors and labels to your plot, You can try this out:

```
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.heatmap(corr,vmin=-1, vmax=1, center=0,cmap=sns.diverging_palette(20, 220, n=200),square=True)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(),rotation=45,horizontalalignment='right')
```

Here cmap parameter handles the mapping from data values to color space.